# Wind Speed binning by mid value with range - Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Im using python 2.7, 
I need a help to find out the solution to do the binning of windspeed with centre of the point. 
Example : i have the binning 0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5.... etc upto 25.0 
needs to group by the above binning, and i needs to do SUM,AVG,STD,MIN,MAX. 
But the thing is if i say 1.5 is the bin value, when i take the average it should be the range from 1.25 to 1.75, i mean mid value, this is the big challange for me.

Can someone help me on this ? below is the sample time series data.

```
period  pt_power_avg    pt_power_sigma  pt_power_max    pt_power_min    turbine_operating_status    turbine_power_avg   turbine_power_sigam turbine_power_min   turbine_power_max   ... site_air_density    normalized_power    normalized_speed    power_coeffient generator_torque    turbulance_intensity    representative_ti_class_a   representative_ti_class_b   representative_ti_class_c   characterstics_ti
date_time                                                                                   
2016-04-11 00:10:00 600.0   457.2   49.57   546.8   350.9   5.0158  468.9   49.17   360.3   561.2   ... 1.09137 513.181976  6.971373    0.370610    313509.882801   0.046929    0.243671    0.213213    0.182754    7.585
2016-04-11 00:20:00 600.0   582.5   18.40   624.7   547.4   5.0169  592.1   18.44   557.5   639.4   ... 1.09028 654.474596  7.583727    0.366787    370016.980236   0.036910    0.233648    0.204442    0.175236    8.175
2016-04-11 00:30:00 600.0   522.9   22.44   573.8   493.4   5.0167  532.4   22.22   501.9   586.1   ... 1.09089 587.183335  7.845861    0.297346    343680.041344   0.018516    0.229871    0.201137    0.172403    8.306
2016-04-11 00:40:00 600.0   482.7   15.98   517.2   448.6   5.0160  492.9   15.92   456.4   529.6   ... 1.09125 541.861655  7.522467    0.311431    325364.977622   0.016373    0.234607    0.205281    0.175955    7.946
2016-04-11 00:50:00 600.0   526.9   25.67   559.2   461.9   5.0169  536.9   25.57   456.8   572.0   ... 1.09125 591.478997  7.794769    0.305551    345429.397866   0.015677    0.230604    0.201778    0.172953    8.228
```

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding what you're asking.  Consider mapping out what you want with much greater clarity.  Use this as a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Basically I needs to group by binning of 0.5,1.0,2.0 ....25.0.. While binning , I needs to take the average based on bin centre values. Example if I wanted to average the value at bin 2.0 , then I have to average the values between 1.75 to 2.25 ,, like this I needs to do it for all the bins.